# How can i make this for loop shorter?

Tags: java, processing

My head is not working anymore. I have to finish this a.s.a.p
How can i make this for loop shorter.

At the moment i have got 4 different for loop. I want to combine them and have only one.

```
Card[] cards = new Card[4*13];

void testCreateCards() {

  int k = 0;
  for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) {               // for suit
    for (int value = 1; value <= 13; value++) {             // from Ace to King
      // build new card
      cards[k++] = new Card(suit, value);
    }
  }
}

void testDrawClubs() {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++) {
    cards[i].displayCard(x, y);
    x +=80;
  }
}

void testDrawDiamonds() {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 80;
  for (int i = 13; i <= 25; i++) {
    cards[i].displayCard(x, y);
    x +=80;
  }
}

void testDrawHearts() {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 160;
  for (int i = 26; i <= 38; i++) {
    cards[i].displayCard(x, y);
    x +=80;
  }
}
void testDrawSpades() {
  int x = 0;
  int y = 240;
  for (int i = 39; i <= 51; i++) {
    cards[i].displayCard(x, y);
    x +=80;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have 4 sets of 13 in one pack. use if or case to create first 13 for clubs, then diamonds and so on. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38726/Basis-of-many-card-games-How-to-make-a-deck-of-car for get an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate x and y directly using [modular arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) because `i % 13` gives you the x-coordinate and `i / 13` gives you the y-coordinate:

```
void testDrawCards() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
        int x = i % 13;
        int y = i / 13;
        cards[i].displayCard(x * 80, y * 80);
    }
 }
```

Comment: modular one is working but the other one is not displaying properly. x, y coordinates are not right

Comment: @baris2: Sorry the if condition was a bit wrong. The modular solution is much cleaner anyway. I think you should just go with that option.